# Why createKeyFromXml() doesn't create language switch key?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-keyboard

I am working on Android Custom Keyboard and it crashes when I launch. I found `createKeyFromXml()` method has a line which creates keys and those keys doesn't create language switch key which cause the app to crash.

The developer guide doesn't say much about it:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html

**LatinKeyboard.Java:**

```
class LatinKeyboard extends Keyboard {
    private Key mEnterKey;
    private Key mSpaceKey;
    private Key mModeChangeKey;
    private Key mLanguageSwitchKey;
    private Key mSavedModeChangeKey;
    private Key mSavedLanguageSwitchKey;

    LatinKeyboard(Context context, int xmlLayoutResId) {
        super(context, xmlLayoutResId);
    }
    public LatinKeyboard(Context context, int layoutTemplateResId,
                         CharSequence characters, int columns, int horizontalPadding) {
        super(context, layoutTemplateResId, characters, columns, horizontalPadding);
    }
    @Override
    protected Key createKeyFromXml(Resources res, Row parent, int x, int y,
                                   XmlResourceParser parser) {
        Key key = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        Log.d("Keys", String.valueOf(key));
        if (key.codes[0] == 10) {
            mEnterKey = key;
        } else if (key.codes[0] == ' ') {
            mSpaceKey = key;
        } else if (key.codes[0] == Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE) {
            mModeChangeKey = key;
            mSavedModeChangeKey = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        } else if (key.codes[0] == LatinKeyboardView.KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH) {
            mLanguageSwitchKey = key;
            mSavedLanguageSwitchKey = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        }
        return key;
    }

    void setLanguageSwitchKeyVisibility(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            mModeChangeKey.width = mSavedModeChangeKey.width;
            mModeChangeKey.x = mSavedModeChangeKey.x;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.width = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.width;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.icon = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.icon;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview;
        } else {
            mModeChangeKey.width = mSavedModeChangeKey.width + mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.width;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.width = 0;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.icon = null;
            mLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview = null;
        }
    }
    void setImeOptions(Resources res, int options) {
        if (mEnterKey == null) {
            return;
        }
        switch (options&(EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) {
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
                mEnterKey.iconPreview = null;
                mEnterKey.icon = null;
                mEnterKey.label = res.getText(R.string.label_go_key);
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                mEnterKey.iconPreview = null;
                mEnterKey.icon = null;
                mEnterKey.label = res.getText(R.string.label_next_key);
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                mEnterKey.icon = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_search_24dp);
                mEnterKey.label = null;
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
                mEnterKey.iconPreview = null;
                mEnterKey.icon = null;
                mEnterKey.label = res.getText(R.string.label_send_key);
                break;
            default:
                mEnterKey.icon = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_24dp);
                mEnterKey.label = null;
                break;
        }
    }
    void setSpaceIcon(final Drawable icon) {
        if (mSpaceKey != null) {
            mSpaceKey.icon = icon;
        }
    }
    private static class LatinKey extends Keyboard.Key {

        LatinKey(Resources res, Keyboard.Row parent, int x, int y,
                 XmlResourceParser parser) {
            super(res, parent, x, y, parser);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isInside(int x, int y) {
            return super.isInside(x, codes[0] == KEYCODE_CANCEL ? y - 10 : y);
        }
    }
}
```

**The error log is:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.sunzala.afghankeyboard, PID: 8894
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at com.sunzala.afghankeyboard.android.LatinKeyboard.setLanguageSwitchKeyVisibility(LatinKeyboard.java:87)
>                         at com.sunzala.afghankeyboard.android.SoftKeyboard.setLatinKeyboard(SoftKeyboard.java:211)
>                         at com.sunzala.afghankeyboard.android.SoftKeyboard.onInitializeInterface(SoftKeyboard.java:151)
>                         at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.initialize(InputMethodService.java:774)

I understand the app crashes because `mModeChangeKey` and `mLanguageSwitchKey` is null and that's because of the method I mentioned. I checked the method and it runs but it doesn't create key which match switch language key code.

I uploaded the app on GitHub if someone is interested to have a look:
https://github.com/maihannijat/AndroidKeyboard

Comment: Please provide enough information. No one knows this question is related to the [sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java#124) you've mentioned in [your old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099182/how-to-add-switch-language-functionality-in-the-android-soft-keyboard).

Comment: @Toris The question doesn't relate to my previous question. The application crash and I find out the reasons but I cannot fix it. If you have a specifict question, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: And from the sample, `private void setLatinKeyboard(LatinKeyboard nextKeyboard) { final boolean shouldSupportLanguageSwitchKey = mInputMethodManager.shouldOfferSwitchingToNextInputMethod(getToken()); nextKeyboard.setLanguageSwitchKeyVisibility(shouldSupportLanguageSwitchKey); }` I think NullPointerException is caused as "nextKeyboard" is null.

Comment: @Toris thanks for the hint. Let me check and will get back to you in few minutes.

Comment: About 'mLanguageSwitchKey' part: [KeyEvent.KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH) > On some devices, the same function may be performed by pressing Shift+Spacebar. I think key.codes[0] doesn't match KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH then. (or maybe in other index if match one exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java#124) code mentioned in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099182/how-to-add-switch-language-functionality-in-the-android-soft-keyboard) shows that NullPointerException will be thrown if "nextKeyboard" is null.

```
private void setLatinKeyboard(LatinKeyboard nextKeyboard) {
    final boolean shouldSupportLanguageSwitchKey =
            mInputMethodManager.shouldOfferSwitchingToNextInputMethod(getToken());
    nextKeyboard.setLanguageSwitchKeyVisibility(shouldSupportLanguageSwitchKey);
    mInputView.setKeyboard(nextKeyboard);
}
```